# How to integrate Socket Mobile Scanner with Android App

Tags: android, bluetooth, barcode-scanner, socketscan

I am trying to use Socket Mobile bluetooth scanner to scan the labels on product. I need to integrate this scanner within my Android app so that when scanner is connected then keyboard will not hide. In short, I need to connect scanner in SPP Mode instead of HID mode so keyboard will not auto-hide/appear on device connect-disconnect.

How can I integrate Socket Mobile's CHS with my Android code? I tried to sample app provided with SocketAPI sdk but getting error `ESKT_UNABLEOPENDEVICE` (number -27) & after few seconds getting error `ESKT_NOTHINGTOLISTEN` (number -47).

Comment: @enrico - **do not** remove clearly relevant tags such as bluetooth.  You may have a useful alternative (for some Android versions) but the question *asked* clearly hinges on the treatment of bluetooth devices and the support (or not) of different profiles by the peripheral.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I removed the bluetooth tag because I thought that, while applicable if this question were on SuperUser, it was not applicable to it here on StackOverflow. The programming question asked is about an sdk, not anything specific about the sdk's bluetooth implementation. Apologies if my interpretation was incorrect.

Comment: The proposal to switch from HID to SPP is very much a bluetooth question (though the answer may well be that the peripheral doesn't support it) and the errors returned are related to the fact that sockets are involved.  You have provided an answer that may well be a solution (and possibly the best one), but is more of a response to a hypothetical superuser version of the question, as it proposes solving the problem by having the user change the device configuration, rather than by changing the program being developed.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to connect scanner in SPP Mode instead of HID mode so keyboard will not auto-hide/appear on device connect-disconnect

You do not need to use SPP mode in order to display the keyboard while the scanner is connected.

> 1. Connect your scanner
> 2. Go to Settings > Language & Input
> 3. Select Default or Current Keyboard for Android 4.x and 5.x, respectively
> 4. Turn `Hardware Physical Keyboard` to off (4.x) or `Show input method` to on (5.x)

Now the virtual keyboard wont auto-hide/show on connect/disconnect

For the `ESKT_UNABLEOPENDEVICE` and `ESKT_NOTHINGTOLISTEN` you'll have to edit your question to provide the complete stacktrace

Comment: I understand your point, but main concern is this that i could not able to do with all devices and some of time anonymous persons will also use my app so i need to integrate SDK & connect scanner in SPP mode.

Comment: No problem, SPP is more robust too. I'm happy to try to help. Please add your logcat output to your question.

Comment: @hchouhan02 Let me know if you need help capturing logcat from the Single Entry application